# How to write custom runtime exception to send a json response with 2 custom information?

Tags: java

The context is:
I'm making a upload csv service and when i do some verification on the content i want to throw a custom runtime exception who contain the error message and the line to the problem.

What i got for now is:

```
public class NotValidCsvException extends RuntimeException {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private Integer _line;

  public NotValidCsvException(final String message, final Integer line) {
    super(formatMessage(message, line));
  }

  public static String formatMessage(String message, Integer line) {
    return new StringBuilder()
               .append("{message: ")
               .append("'")
               .append(message)
               .append("'")
               .append(", ligne: ")
               .append("'")
               .append(line)
               .append("'")
               .append("}").toString();
  }
}
```

But the problem is that i got a response like:

```
{"timestamp":1511785651810,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.sstrn.pa.service.impl.exception.NotValidCsvException","message":"{"message": "message_import_csv_undefined_thing", "line": 0}"}
```

But i'd like to have something like:

```
{"timestamp":1511785651810,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.sstrn.pa.service.impl.exception.NotValidCsvException","message":"message_import_csv_undefined_thing", "line": 0}
```

Comment: ehm ... just the same way you create any other composed object, but this one extends (Runtime)Exception?

Comment: But the idea is to have 'errCode' in the json response fired

Comment: ok.. and?  I don't see the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your question says nothing about JSON, or a "response" that gets "fired;" nor is it at all clear why the question you linked doesn't answer your question.

Comment: The problem is that i want to get the message, and the custom string accessible in my response in my front so i can do something like: response.message and response.errCode

Comment: We'd have an easier time understanding your question if you construct a [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do and how it's not working.

Comment: I did some edit, i hope my problem is more clear that way

Answer (score 0):

So to do this i created and interface AttributeLineEnabled whose implemented by my NotValidCsvException.

```
public interface AttributeLineEnabled {
  public Integer  getLine();
}

public class NotValidCsvException extends RuntimeException implements AttributeLineEnabled {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Integer _line;

  public NotValidCsvException(final String message) {
    super(message);
  }

  public NotValidCsvException(final String message, Integer line) {
    super(message);
    _line = line;
  }

  public Integer getLine() {
    return _line;
  }

  public void setLine(final Integer line) {
    _line = line;
  }
}
```

Then i created a controller who extends DefaultErrorAttributes and implement ErrorAttributes.
This controller override the getErrorAttributes method who set the jsonResponse.

```
public class BaseErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes implements ErrorAttributes  {

private static final String LINE = "line";

public BaseErrorAttributes() {
    super();
}

 public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
     Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
     Throwable error = getError(requestAttributes);
     if (error instanceof AttributeLineEnabled) {
         AttributeLineEnabled attributeLineEnabled= (AttributeLineEnabled) error;
         errorAttributes.put(LINE, attributeLineEnabled.getLine());
     }
     return errorAttributes;
 }
}
```

And i inject it into my controller who make the importation process:

```
private BaseErrorAttributes _baseErrorAttributes;
// getter and setter too
```